# Jquery .append no me agrega los inputs en la tabla

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo que no me funciona.
$(document).ready(funcPrincipal());

```
      function funcPrincipal()
      {
        $("#btnNuevoAlineamiento").on('click', funcNuevoAlineamiento());

      }


function funcNuevoAlineamiento()
              {
              $("#tablaAlineamientos")
              .append
              (
                $('<tr>')
                    .append
                    (
                      $('<td>')
                        .append
                        (
                          $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'estrategias[]')
                        )
                    )
                    .append
                    (
                      $('<td>')
                        .append
                        (
                          $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'alineamientos[]')
                        )
                    )
                    .append
                    (
                      $('<td>').addClass('text-center')
                        .append
                        (
                          $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
                        )
                    )
                );

              }
```

y la tabla es la siguiente:

```
 <label for="tablaAlineamientos">
              Agregar grupo familiar
              <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevoAlineamiento">Nuevo</div>
            </label>
            <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaAlineamientos">
                <tr>
                  <th>Estrategia</th>
                  <th>Alineamiento</th>
                  <th>Opciones</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estrategias[]" value=""></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="alineamientos[]"  value=""></td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                    <div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: No puedes añadir un append dentro de otro apppend

Comment: ¿Esto qué tiene que ver con SQL?

Comment: @jachguate ahi lo cambie, disculpas.

Comment: @WilsonFreddyAndiaAlborta Entonces como agregarias un input ???

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: @jachguate que cuando se presione btnNuevoAlineamiento en la tabla se genere una fila con inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar una *nueva fila*, agrega directamente el código HTML a la tabla, por ejemplo así:

```js
function funcNuevoAlineamiento() {
  $("#tablaAlineamientos").append(`<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estrategias[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="alineamientos[]"  value=""></td>
    <td class="text-center"><div class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</div></td>
  </tr>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="tablaAlineamientos">Agregar grupo familiar
   <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevoAlineamiento" onclick="funcNuevoAlineamiento()">Nuevo</div>
</label>
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaAlineamientos">
  <tr>
    <th>Estrategia</th>
    <th>Alineamiento</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estrategias[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="alineamientos[]"  value=""></td>
    <td class="text-center"><div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Haz clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"* para probar mi solución aquí mismo en el navegador.

Comment: Funciona 10 puntos. Si le agrego algun contador en la **function funcNuevoAlineamiento()** para asi puedo obtener los valores de los inputs?

Comment: Si claro, puedes ir numerándolos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria de esta manera:

```js
  function funcPrincipal()
      {
        $("#btnNuevoAlineamiento").on('click', funcNuevoAlineamiento());

      }


function funcNuevoAlineamiento()
              {
              
              let contenido=`<tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='estrategias[]'>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='alineamientos[]'>
                                </td>
                                <td class='text-center'>
                                    <input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='eliminar'>
                                </td>`;
              $("#tablaAlineamientos")
              .append
              (contenido);

              }
```

Ahora tambien Puedes Trabajar Con CreateElement Que son crear etiquetas HtmL y agregarlas como hermanas...